# Applying different functions to different columns of a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a MATLAB matrix with 2 columns in which I would like to apply separate functions to each column. Specifically, I want to add 5 to one column, and 3 to the other.

For example,

```
a = 0 4
    2 5
    3 7
    . .
    . .
    . .
```

would become

```
a = 5 9
    7 10
    8 12
    . .
    . .
    . .
```

I know I can add the *same* value to both column with a simple `a = a + x`, but in this case I am trying to assign different numbers to add to each side.

Comment: you probably mean: "would become {5 7},{7 8},{8 10}. ."

Comment: @CaptainProg: Why not accepting the more general solution, which is already built-in matlab and thus quicker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could easily add the numbers like the following:

```
a = ones(5, 2)
b = [2 5]
c = bsxfun(@plus, a, b)
```

which will give you:

```
a =
     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
     1     1

b =
     2     5

c =
     3     6
     3     6
     3     6
     3     6
     3     6
```

`bsxfun` also offers a lot more operations, look here: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html

Answer (score 1):

A different way of doing this, this time using [repmat](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html):

```
>> a = [0 4; 2 5; 3 7; 1 2]

a =

 0     4
 2     5
 3     7
 1     2

>> a = a + repmat([5, 3], size(a, 1), 1)

a =

 5     7
 7     8
 8    10
 6     5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below

```
a(:,1)=a(:,1)+5;
a(:,2)=a(:,2)+3;
```

**Edit:**
More General Code :D

```
function [Result]=AddColumn(A, B)
    [aRows aCols]=size(A);
    [bRows bCols]=size(B);

    if(aCols~=bCols || bRows>1)
        ErrorMessage='not Matched'
        return;
    end;

    B=B'
    X=B*ones(1,aRows);
    X=X';
    Result=A+X;
end
```

Comment: Won't be nice programming style for more some more columns, which can be done quite easily with bsxfun, which is probably even faster for huge numbers :)

Comment: Agreed, BSXFUN is the way forward for this sort of thing. Shame it has such a non-obvious name, and takes quite a big (IMHO) of getting used to.

Comment: @ColHeather you can see my Edit for more General option

Comment: @Edric You can see my Edit for more General option

Comment: @ajavan Did you test your code? What's "ErrorMessage" supposed to do? Why are you using complex-conjugate transposes? (In fact, why are you using transposes at all?) Why wouldn't you just use Col Heather's BSXFUN one-liner?

Comment: @Edric it's nothing, just to print a message in command window (without ;  ;) ), using build-in functions instead of loop in Matlab, helps you to write a fast code, just try it.